# how i can fix this problem in python code

Tags: python-3.x, function

I'm new programmer and I am begginer, this my first time use stack overflow, I trying now to calcul a calculator calcul numbers like normal calculator, I want write something such as (" 7 - 2 * 3") and the code give the result.
The code is chaos im just begginer so please just try understand that and help me.

when you try the code input numbers and operators with space like this 5 + 5.
This the code :

```
from functools import reduce

question = input("Enter your calcul : ")

nums = question.split()

numbers = nums[0::2]

def calcul(num1, num2):
    
    for x in variation:
        
        if x == '+':
            return num1 + num2
        elif x == '-':
            return num1 - num2
        elif x == '*':
            return num1 * num2
        elif x == '/':
            return num1 / num2
    

def wayy(lt):
    for x in lt:
        if '+' == x :
            yield'+'
        if '-' == x :
            yield'-'
        if '*' == x :
            yield'*'
        if '/' == x :
            yield'/'

variations = [] # [ + , - , * , / ]
variation = wayy(nums)
for x in variation:
    variations.append(x)

print(variations)

nm = []
for n in numbers:
    n = int(n)
    nm.append(n)

calcule = reduce(calcul, nm)
print(calcule)
```

I try coding a calculator and i have a problem i think it is in calcul function when i input the numbers the result is "None" I know the problem in function (calcul) but I dont know how I can fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only change "variation" to "variations" in the "calcul" function.

```
def calcul(num1, num2):

    for x in variations:
        if x == '+':
            return num1 + num2
        elif x == '-':
            return num1 - num2
        elif x == '*':
            return num1 * num2
        elif x == '/':
            return num1 / num2
```

Since "variation" is a "Generator" object, but "variations" is a list of Strings (what you need).